# Javadoc de JSF não localizado no Netbeans

Tags: jsf, netbeans, javadoc

Uso o Netbeans 7.2.1 e queria saber porque somente o Javadoc de objetos do Java (java.lang, java.io, etc) são mostrados. Todos os outros (javax.*) mostra algo do tipo:

> **javax.​faces.​context**
>
> public abstract class FacesContext extends Object
>
> *O Javadoc não foi localizado. A documentação do Javadoc não existe para este item ou você não adicionou o Javadoc especificado no
>   Gerenciador de Plataformas Java ou no Gerenciador de Bibliotecas.*

Já tentei incluir a URL http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api no gerenciador de plataforma Java `Ferramentas > Plataforma java > Javadoc` mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 2):

Você fez o correto para adicionar o Javadoc para a JDK, mas não **para bibliotecas e componentes  que estão fora da JDK** , como por exemplo o JSF, referenciado na sua pergunta.

Para adicionar o Javadoc desses componentes no NetBeans, você primeiro deve baixar esse Javadoc no site oficial da biblioteca ou usar o Javadoc online da própria biblioteca. Depois, crie seu projeto no NetBeans. Com o projeto criado:

1. Clique com o botão direito no projeto e selecione **Propriedades**;
2. Selecione no menu a esquerda **Bibliotecas**;
3. Na aba **Compilar**, selecione a biblioteca que você quer adicionar o Javadoc;
4. Clique no botão **Editar**;
5. Clique na aba **Javadoc**;
6. Adicione o arquivo baixado ou a URL do Javadoc;
7. Fim;

Comment: Em propriedades do projeto não existe o menu Bibliotecas. No item Compilar eu só tenho como selecionar ou gerenciar a plataforma (JDK)